# Docker: Why can't a simple Dockerfile HEALTHCHECK based on grepping be accepted by docker?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, grep

If I understand correctly, and based on the examples out there, the healthcheck command keeps the flag "starting" until the flag returns code 0, then it becomes "healthy". I'm unable to reach that state with this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# find "sleep infinity" in ps -ax, and use as a way to decide that the execution finished
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=30s --interval=30s --timeout=4s --retries=1000 CMD [ "$(ps -ax | grep -i "sleep infinity" | grep -v grep | wc -l)" == 2 ] || exit 1

CMD echo "Hello, we're done with what we're supposed to do" && sleep infinity
```

The purpose of this Dockerfile is to block ad-infinitum once all the processes required finish successfully. The healthcheck will be used in docker-compose to order the container execution. In practice, this is just an updater that has to run first before anything else.

By building and running the container:

```
$ docker build . -t mytest
$ docker run  --name mytest-cont mytest
```

Then we can run in another terminal

```
$ watch docker ps
```

and we'll see that the state "health: starting" never changes.

The weird part is that the command used for health check works fine. If we enter the container:

```
$ docker exec -it mytest-cont /bin/bash
```

Then run that command, as copy pasted, then check the exit code, it returns zero:

```
$ [ "$(ps -ax | grep -i "sleep infinity" | grep -v grep | wc -l)" == 2 ]
$ echo $?
```

where we see the returned value is zero!

So... the command works in bash. Why is it not working as expected in docker and being accepted as healthcheck command to report the health of the container in `docker ps`?

Comment: Your container never actually does anything.  If this is just running an initialization task, and you're using the extended syntax of Compose `depends_on:`, can you set its `condition: service_completed_successfully`, have its CMD do whatever initialization tasks, and exit rather than sleep forever?  This is documented in the [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1) but also [appears to be supported](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/service.py#L758) in version 2.x Compose files with the Python implementation of Compose.

Comment: @DavidMaze you're totally right. There's, though, a potential issue I'm worried about with service_completed_successfully, which is that adding containers to compose (which is a requirement) will force rerunning the initialization, which is only OK if the whole system is restarted. The sleep that I made provides a guarantee that this will never happen. Running that initialization while part of the services are running can lead to data corruption. Not sure how to make that guarantee without that blocking sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD` is running commands with `sh`, not `bash`.

So you need to do `= 2` instead of `== 2`

Comment: Thank you very much. Brilliant, I have to say. I didn't catch this. This taught me to notice something I never thought of looking into.